# ASP.Net Security

Tags: asp.net, security

There's a great pdf available from the Microsoft Patterns & Practices team called: "building secure asp.net applications".
[microsoft pdf](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=055FF772-97FE-41B8-A58C-BF9C6593F25E&displaylang=en)

This is a bit old now since it was written for .Net 1.0. Does anyone know if Microsoft have published an update or equivalent?

Thanks

Rob.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a Security Guideline for ASP.NET 2.0: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998258.aspx

Comment: Even this documentation has been retired - anyone know if there's a new set?

Answer (score 1):

How's this - ASP.NET Web Application Security
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/330a99hc.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the book [Beginning ASP.NET Security](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Beginning-ASP-NET-Security-Wrox-Programmer/dp/0470743654/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1336063798&sr=8-1) by [blowdart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2525/blowdart).